# How do I install Apex Dataloader?

Tags: data-loader

I have downloaded the files from `sourceforge` and extracted the zip files, but what do I do to install it?

I'm on Windows 8.1 Surface Pro 3.

Answer (score 4):

The sourceforge download is most likely the source code for Data Loader, not the actually installable exe for Windows.

To download the current supported version of Data Loader, log into your org, go to **Setup > Data Management > Data Loader**

From there, you should be able to install.

As of now, according to the [official open source repo on github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader), Data Loader is supported on Windows 7 and XP. So your mileage may vary with Windows 8. But give it a try.

As of Summer 15, the next upcoming release Data Loader is set to expand support to Mac OSX.

Comment: until then, for Mac, use LexiLoader

Answer (score 0):

Once you download and install while try to login for first time you might receive invalid credentials error. In that case you might need to reset your security token and new code need to attach to your password to login